# Obtener datos del navegador y dispositivo en Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue3

> Edit 24/8 - Voy a ponerle recompensa a esta pregunta para ver si alguien podría explicarme cómo reemplazar esta funcion, para que funcione globalmente en Vue 3.

```
const device = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.$device = devices()
    }
}
```

> La respuesta que yo mismo publiqué, si bien me sirvió para cumplir el propósito buscado, requiere mover unos archivos. Me gustaría poder modificar el plugin para que funcione global, haciendo uso de `app.use(directive)` en mi archivo `main.js`.

Como dice la pregunta, quiero obtener datos del usuario. Esto debido a que quiero aplicar un `css` diferente en `android chrome`, ya que la barra de direcciones ocupa parte de la pantalla y no se ve el sitio completo.

Intenté con el plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-device-detector-js

Recibo el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$device' of undefined
at Object.install (index.js:90)
at Object.use (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4136)
at eval (main.js:50)
at Module../src/main.js (app.js:7989)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
at fn (app.js:151)
at Object.1 (app.js:8758)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
at app.js:925
```

Este es el código del plugin, por si alguien podría encontrar la manera de que Vue 3 no tenga el error con la variable `$device`

```
import DeviceDetector from "device-detector-js";
import BotDetector from "device-detector-js/dist/parsers/bot";


const deviceDetector = new DeviceDetector();
const detector = deviceDetector.parse(window.navigator.userAgent);
const botDetector = new BotDetector();
const bot = botDetector.parse(window.navigator.userAgent);

function devices() {

    return {

        isMobile: detector.device.type == "smartphone",
        isTablet: detector.device.type == "tablet",
        isDesktop: detector.device.type == "desktop",

        model: detector.device.model,
        brand: detector.device.brand,
        type: detector.device.type,
        os_name: detector.os,
        os_platform: detector.os.platform,
        os_version: detector.os.version,
        browser_name: detector.client.name,
        browser_version: detector.client.version,
        browser_engine: detector.client.engine,
        browser_engine_version: detector.client.engineVersion,

        browser: {
            chrome: detector.client.name == "Chrome",
            chrome_view: detector.client.name == "Chrome Webview",
            chrome_mobile: detector.client.name == "Chrome Mobile",
            chrome_mobile_ios: detector.client.name == "Chrome Mobile iOS",
            safari: detector.client.name == "Safari",
            safari_mobile: detector.client.name == "Mobile Safari",
            msedge: detector.client.name == "Microsoft Edge",
            msie_mobile: detector.client.name == "IE Mobile",
            msie: detector.client.name == "Internet Explorer"
        },

        os: {
            android: detector.os.name == "Android",
            blackberry: detector.os.name == "BlackBerry OS",
            ios: detector.os.name == "iOS",
            windows: detector.os.name == "Windows",
            windows_phone: detector.os.name == "Windows Phone",
            mac: detector.os.name == "Mac",
            linux: detector.os.name == "GNU/Linux" || detector.os.name == "GNU\/Linux",
            chrome: detector.os.name == "Chrome OS",
            firefox: detector.os.name == "Firefox OS",
            gamingConsole: detector.os.name == "Gaming Console"
        },

        isAndroid: detector.os.name == "Android",
        isBlackberry: detector.os.name == "BlackBerry OS",
        isIOS: detector.os.name == "iOS",
        isWindows: detector.os.name == "Windows",
        isWindowsPhone: detector.os.name == "Windows Phone",
        isOsx: detector.os.name == "Mac",
        isLinux: detector.os.name == "GNU/Linux" || detector.os.name == "GNU\/Linux",
        isChromeOs: detector.os.name == "Chrome OS",
        isFireFoxOS: detector.os.name == "Firefox OS",
        GamingConsole: detector.os.name == "Gaming Console",
        isBot: bot,



        machine: {
            brand: detector.device.brand,
            model: detector.device.model,
            os_name: detector.os.name,
            os_version: detector.os.version,
            type: detector.device.type,
        },
        bot: bot,
        client: detector.client,
        device: detector.device
    }


}

const device = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.$device = devices()
    }
}


export default device
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando creas un plugin en Vue 3 necesita ser un objecto que tenga la función `install`.

Digamos que tu plugin se llama `Device`, tu plugin lo puedes crear así:

```js
// device.js
export default {
  install (app) {
    app.provide('device', 'world')

    // Tambien puedes usar `config.globalProperties`
    // y `device` esta disponible usando `this.device`
    // pero veo que usas la API de composición, por lo que
    // creo que queda mejor usar `provide`
    // en otro caso puedes usar la siguiente linea
    // app.config.globalProperties.device = 'world'
  }
}
```

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Device from './device'

createApp(App)
  .use(Device)
  .mount('#app')
```

Y simplemente lo usas en un componente:

```
<template>
  hello {{ device }}
</template>

<script>
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup () {
    const device = inject('device')

    // lo usas en un computed, watch etc...

    return { device }
  }
}
</script>
```

En mi caso `device` es un simple `'world'`, pero ahí puede ir una función, un objeto,
o cualquier cosa, en tu caso la función `devices()`.

---

Estas 2 formas de agregar puedes bucarlas en la doc:

- [`app.provide`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/global-api.html#provide-inject)
- [`config.globalProperties`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/global-api.html#config-ignoredelements-is-now-config-compileroptions-iscustomelement)

Answer (score 4):

Finalmente lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

Habiendo instalado el plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-device-detector-js), copié el contenido de `/node_modules/vue-device-detector-js/index.js` y lo guardé en un archivo local en `.src/utils/detect-device.js`. (Las dependencias .ts las dejé en la carpeta `/node_modules`, donde ya estaban).

Luego, en este nuevo archivo `.src/utils/detect-device.js`, modifiqué este código (depreciado para vue 3)

```
const device = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.$device = devices()
    }
}
```

por esta línea

```
const device = devices()
```

Ahora en `App.vue` importo el `.js`

```
import device from './utils/detect-device'
```

Y ya puedo usarlo en el componente:

```
  onMounted(() => {
      console.log(`Modelo: ${device.model} - marca: ${device.brand}`)
      console.log(`Navegador: ${device.browser_name} - version: ${device.browser_version}`);
      console.log(`Es movil?: ${device.isMobile} - Es android? ${device.isAndroid} - Es iOS?: ${device.isIOS}`)
      console.log(`isChromeOS? - ${device.isChromeOs}`)
      console.log(`SO android? ${device.os.android} - windows? ${device.os.windows} - mac? ${device.os.mac}`)
    });
```

> **EXTRA:**

Entiendo que lo correcto seria reemplazar

```
const device = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.$device = devices()
    }
}
```

Por la forma correcta para Vue 3 que modifica las `globalOptions`. Como no entiendo tan profundamente el framework para hacer esto, en lugar de darle uso global, lo traje como un objeto local y cumplió su propósito sin problemas.

Answer (score 4):

yo utilizo esta funcion que hice en vanilla javascript por lo que la puedes usar con el framework de tu preferencia

```javascript
function getOS () {

  const isThere = 'navigator' in window;
  let os = "";
  const userAgent = isThere && 'userAgent' in navigator && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() || '';
  const vendor = isThere && 'vendor' in navigator && navigator.vendor.toLowerCase() || '';
  const appVersion = isThere && 'appVersion' in navigator && navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase() || '';
  const platform = isThere && 'platform' in navigator && navigator.platform.toLowerCase() || '';

  if (/iphone/i.test(userAgent) || /ipad/i.test(userAgent) || /ipod/i.test(userAgent)) os = 'ios';
  if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) os = 'android'
  if (/win/i.test(appVersion) && /phone/i.test(userAgent)) os = 'windowsPhone'
  if (/mac/i.test(appVersion)) os = 'MacOSX'
  if (/win/i.test(appVersion)) os = 'windows'
  if (/linux/i.test(appVersion)) os = 'linux'

  return {
    os,
    userAgent,
    vendor,
    appVersion,
    platform,
  }
}
```

Comment: Te agradezco por el aporte, lo voy a probar luego, pero te comento que la recompensa es para quien logre adaptar la función que modifica las ``globalOptions`` para la version 3 de Vue